# Python 2.7: Names of unicode representations

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, unicode-escapes, unicode-literals

What are the names for these different kinds of ascii representations of unicode?

- `\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2`
- `\U0001f622`

And is there a term for the set that they belong to that's more specific than "representation"? And in the context of these, how would I describe the non-ascii representation ()?

Since I don't know what to call them it is very hard to search for how to work with them.

Thanks!

Comment: This seems like a language-specific question or at least would have language-specific answers. Also, where the hex byte format is allowed, it's not a given that the bytes are interpreted as Unicode. For example, not allowed in C#. In JavaScript, it represents bytes from ISO 8859-1 that are then put into the string as Unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tom Blodget already warned you, this is a somewhat python specific answer.

---

The leading `\` shows that it's an escape sequence.

`\x` means that the next two characters will be interpreted as a hex digit.

`\U` means that the next eight characters will be interpreted as a 32-bit hex value.

You can read more about that here:

> https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

To fully answer your question:

- `\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2` are simply four ASCII characters and you have their hex values
- `\U0001f622` is a UNICODE codepoint encoded with a 32-bit hex value
- is a glyph or simply a special character.

Comment: The first is also the UTF-8 encoding of the second.

Comment: Hex values outside the range `\x00` to `\x7f` aren't ASCII. That's not a 16-bit hex value, it's 32 bits. And the technical term is "codepoint", not "character".

Comment: Yup, I confused hex values with hex digits. 8 Hex digits means 32-bits, you're right, I edited the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom Do you mean for the second bullet point in this answer it should read _"`\U0001f622` is a UNICODE codepoint"_ ?

Comment: @NathanHinchey exactly.

Answer (score 1):

**For Python 3**

First there seems to be a misunderstanding about the hex escapes:

```
print("\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2" == "\u00F0\u009F\u0098\u00A2")
print("\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2" == "\U000000F0\U0000009F\U00000098\U000000A2")
print("\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2" == "\U000000F0\U0000009F\U00000098\U000000A2")
print("\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2" == "\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH}\N{APPLICATION PROGRAM COMMAND}\N{START OF STRING}\N{CENT SIGN}")
```

and for completeness (I recall using octal effectively in machine code where some instructions had 3-bit, aligned arguments but I don't see the point in real programming):

```
print("\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2" == "\360\237\230\242")
```

It appears they are all Unicode **codepoint** escapes in 2-digit hexadecimal, 4-digit hexadecimal, and 8-digit hexadecimal, with ranges from U+0000 to U+00FF, U+FFFF, and U+10FFFF, respectively.

We can confirm that, unlike other languages where the \u for is for a UTF-16 code unit, in Python 3, it is really a codepoint.

```
print("\ud83d\ude22" == "\U0000d83d\U0000de22")
```

and for completeness:

```
print("\U0001f622" == "")
print("\N{CRYING FACE}" == "")
```

In other languages (where they would be two UTF-16 code units), `"\ud83d\ude22"` would equal `""`.

Now, U+D8ED and U+DE22 are Unicode codepoints designated as surrogates. In other words, not *characters.* They reserve the codepoint codespace for the UTF-16 code units with corresponding values. This is the way the USC-2 encoding of Unicode was transparently extended to UTF-16 when Unicode was expanded from 2^16 codepoints to 2^21 codepoints. For more information see the [Unicode FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

---

As [@Robᵩ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8747/rob%e1%b5%a9) points out, you can have a bytestring literal, too:

```
print("\U0001f622".encode("utf-8") == b"\xF0\x9F\x98\xA2")
```

Comment: The treatment of `\u` may depend on the version and build of Python you're using. For me, `u"\ud83d\ude22" == u'\U0001f622'` yields `True` on 2.7 but `False` on 3.6.